# reCAPTCHA needs to be configured with a public & private key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I am using ReCaptcha in my MVC Application.I am able to build this application but getting an error "reCAPTCHA needs to be configured with a public & private key"
I have declared the Private and Public Key in Web.Config file as well.But same error.Is there any way to generate the Private and Public Key on the Application load so that no one can tamper it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with reCAPTCHA, but isn't the key you mention the plain old API key used to *authenticate* with the service? (For purposes of rate control, etc.) That is, one issued to your application by reCAPTCHA - how do you propose generating it?

Comment: When do you get this error? Does it happen as soon as you start the application, or is it displayed on the stare page?

Comment: yes i have added the  @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha()) in View and above the page i mentioned as @using Recaptcha...i have added this at Registration page i have a button called as Register on clicking it it throws me the error...

Comment: Solved this issue by own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using reCAPTCHA in tandem with [PoliteCaptcha](https://github.com/NuGet/PoliteCaptcha) for a while now in our MVC4 application, and this is my current working implementation :

**Web.Config**

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="reCAPTCHA::PublicKey" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />
     <add key="reCAPTCHA::PrivateKey" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" />  
</appSettings>
```

**RegisterUser.cshtml**

Make sure you have a using at the top of the page :

```
@using PoliteCaptcha
```

Depending on where you what the captcha to appear if it's triggered, this will render the HTML :

```
@Html.SpamPreventionFields()
```

Then in the `@Scripts` section of this page I use the extension helper, but you can just as easily reference the script directly :

```
@section Scripts
{    
   @Html.SpamPreventionScript()
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")  
}
```

**RegisterUserController.cs**

Then annotate the method that is called when you'd like to verify if it's a real user :

```
[HttpPost, ValidateSpamPrevention]
public ActionResult RegisterUser(RegisterUserModel request)
{
    // ...
}
```

If the page interaction has triggered the captcha, then `Model.IsValid` will return `false` here, and will then display the HTML generated by `@Html.SpamPreventionFields`.

Answer (score 2):

You can create the keys that @millimoose is referring to on https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

Documented here
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro